# How to remove a white line in the cell of my html table?

Tags: html, cell

I am making a 5x5 table which will contain images, though on some of the squares I get a white line on the bottom of the cell. (note that I put a gold background so you could notice the line easier)

image of the problem
https://i.stack.imgur.com/jpXDx.png

I have tried adding "vertical-align: bottom;" , cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0", but still the same problem.

css:

```
<style>
table {
  width: 90%;
}
td {
  width: 18%;
  position: relative;
border: 2px solid black;
}
td:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  margin-top: 100%;
}
td .content {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
background-color: gold;
}
img {
  width: 100%;
display: block;
}
</style>
```

html:

```
<table align="center">
  <tr>
    <td><div class="content"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/90"></div></td>
    <td><div class="content"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/90"></div></td>
    <td><div class="content"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/90"></div></td>
<td><div class="content"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/90"></div></td>
<td><div class="content"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/90"></div></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><div class="content"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/120"></div></td>
    <td><div class="content"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/120"></div></td>
    <td><div class="content"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/120"></div></td>
<td><div class="content"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/90"></div></td>
<td><div class="content"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/120"></div></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><div class="content"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/120"></div></td>
    <td><div class="content"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/120"></div></td>
    <td><div class="content"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/120"></div></td>
<td><div class="content"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/90"></div></td>
<td><div class="content"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/120"></div></td>
  </tr>
<tr>
    <td><div class="content"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/120"></div></td>
    <td><div class="content"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/120"></div></td>
    <td><div class="content"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/120"></div></td>
<td><div class="content"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/90"></div></td>
<td><div class="content"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/120"></div></td>
  </tr>
<tr>
    <td><div class="content"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/120"></div></td>
    <td><div class="content"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/120"></div></td>
    <td><div class="content"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/120"></div></td>
<td><div class="content"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/90"></div></td>
<td><div class="content"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/120"></div></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I expect to get rid of the lines in the cells.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you add `height: 100%;` to your image css the gold area will be covered up.

I also added `overflow: hidden;` to the `.content` area to prevent the larger images from overlapping with the new 100% fix.

All changes have been labeled 'Below is new' in the css of the fiddle below.

```css
table {
  width: 90%;
  /* Below is new */
  border-spacing: 2px;  
}

td {
  width: 18%;
  position: relative;
  border: 2px solid black;
}

td:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  margin-top: 100%;
}

td .content {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-color: gold;
  /* Below is new */
  overflow: hidden;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  /* Below is new */
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<table align="center">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div class="content"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/90"></div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div class="content"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/90"></div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div class="content"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/90"></div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div class="content"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/90"></div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div class="content"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/90"></div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div class="content"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/120"></div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div class="content"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/120"></div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div class="content"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/120"></div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div class="content"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/90"></div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div class="content"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/120"></div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div class="content"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/120"></div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div class="content"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/120"></div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div class="content"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/120"></div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div class="content"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/90"></div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div class="content"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/120"></div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div class="content"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/120"></div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div class="content"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/120"></div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div class="content"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/120"></div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div class="content"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/90"></div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div class="content"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/120"></div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div class="content"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/120"></div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div class="content"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/120"></div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div class="content"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/120"></div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div class="content"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/90"></div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div class="content"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/120"></div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Are there supposed to be white spaces between each box?

Comment: absolutely not, there is no white spaces between each box on my website. They are all glued to each other just like in the image I posted. Though I wouldn't mind have it like that with the white spaces between each box! It actually looks better.

Comment: Awesome, does this answer your question/resolve your issue?

Comment: it doesn't, how do I make so I get the white spaces between each box? Do I do that with "margin" ? And I actually would also like to know how to remove the white line (my original question) with the image I provided.

Comment: White space between each box is adding `table { border-spacing: 2px; }` and the explanation above should solve the gold line issue from the question

Comment: I added comments to my code above, if it doesnt work it could be something else with your environment because the fiddle is functioning on my end